# Does anonymous can access current node? How to check it in my module?

Tags: 7, hooks, users

I need to do something witn current node by my module only if anonymous users can view this node. How to check it?

By default I use `$node->status == 1`, but some other modules can change anonymous access rights also for published nodes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does anonymous can access current node? How to check it in my module?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/does-anonymous-can-access-current-node-how-to-check-it-in-my-module)

Comment: Actually, it's the other question that is the duplicate of this one, as this question has been asked earlier, even if in a different site. The questions should be probably merged.

Answer (score 1):

The check if the anonymous user has access to a given `$node`, you can use the [`node_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_access/7) like this: `node_access('view', $node, user_load(0))`.

As a side note, `$node->status == 1` will check that the node is published. An unpublished node is usually not visible by anonymous user. Which users are allowed to view unpublished node depends on the granted permissions and node access module enabled on the site.

Comment: If I give the "view own unpublished content" permission to the anonymous users, they will be able to see the unpublished nodes assigned to the anonymous user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a special module to set node permissions? Or just core Drupal?

If just core Drupal, then I think anonymous users only need the "access content" permission, and maybe you could check this with (I have not tested this code):

```
$anonymous = user_load(0); // load anonymous user
$can_access_content = user_access('access content', $anonymous);
```

Comment: Drupal 7 uses a different permission.