# Content profile bug - cannot edit user profile page

Tags: users

If the administrator user creates a profile node for a user, then that user cannot edit his own profile. How can I solve this problem? I have looked on the Content Profile module's issues, and found similar problems but no solutions for that.

In my case, that user created his profile node by himself, but I changed his username through phpmyadmin; now, his profile node results created by the admin user, not himself.

**Problem solved!** that profile node had php input format and that user whom i edited profile hadn't access for php input format filter.

Comment: Heihachi please post an answer to your question that includes the solution instead of putting it inside the question

Answer (score 2):

The Content Profile module associates a node with a user.  If the administrative user adds a profile node, then it is authored by the administrator.  Therefore, the user that the profile node was created for will not have access to edit the node since they are not the author.  As an administrator, make sure to change the "Authored by" field to be the user whose profile the node belongs to, then the user will have the ability to edit it.

Comment: Watched in phpmyadmin {node} found that profile node and it has author ID → same as that user ID (Whom i've created the node profile as user 1). Whats the problem?

Comment: Did you set Drupal permissions for the user to edit and create content of that type?

Comment: Sure i did that.

Comment: Have you tried using the Devel Node Access module?  That is usually the best way to determine why a user can or cannot view/edit/delete a node.

Comment: how to check it with devel node access?

Comment: For more info on Devel Node Access, refer to [this answer](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8651/does-anonymous-can-access-current-node-how-to-check-it-in-my-module/8658#8658)